# problems with data storage into firebase with ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am trying to save data into firebase using Ionic 2. When I use the web version, data are well saved, but once I build the apk and I install it on my phone, if I try to save, nothing happend and data are not saved. 
What could be the reason of that ?

Here is the code of the function used to send data to forebase.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    private flo:FirebaseListObservable<any>;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public afdb: AngularFireDatabase, public toast: ToastController){
        this.flo = afdb.list('/logements');
    }

    save(){
        try{
            this.flo.push({
                nom: "donald",
                prenom: "trumpy",
                tel: "+1 00000001",
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.toast.create({
                    message: "saved",
                    duration: 2000,
                    showCloseButton: true
                });
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
        catch(e){
            this.toast.create({ message: "error" + e.message });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console if you run the app with the mobile connected to the PC/Mac?

Comment: no errors in the console. just two warnings                                         -Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator                                     -util.js:60 Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
cordovaWarn @ util.js:60